# OBIEE 12c issue using multiple ldap servers on MSAD Provider

Tags: ldap, weblogic12c, obiee

I am using OBIEE 12c for BI Analytics. The LDAP authentication is set up in WebLogic by creating MSAD_Provider.

Security Realm -> myrealm -> Providers -> MSAD_Provider

Under Configuration -> Common, I set:

> Control Flag = SUFFICIENT

Under Configuration -> Provider Specific, here are the following settings:

> *Connection*
>
> Host: ldap1.domain.com ldap2.domain.com
>
> Port: 389
>
> Principal: AD user with admin/read access to users and groups
>   information.
>
> Credential: password for the Principal user specified above.
>
> *Users*
>
> User Base DN: OU where all users exist.
>
> All Users Filter: (&(sAMAccountName=*)(objectclass=user))
>
> User From Name Filter: (&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user))
>
> User Search Scope: subtree
>
> User Name Attribute: sAMAccountName
>
> User Object class: user
>
> *Groups*
>
> Group Base DN: OU where all groups exist.
>
> All Groups Filter: (&(CN=*)(objectclass=group))
>
> Group From Name Filter: (&(CN=%g)(objectclass=group))
>
> Group Search Scope: subtree
>
> Group Membership Searching: unlimited
>
> Max Group Membership Search Level: 10
>
> *General*
>
> Connect Timeout: 30
>
> Connect Retry Limit: 1
>
> Parallel Connect Delay: 0
>
> Result Time Limit: 0

After saving and applying all the changes, it's time for me to test if LDAP server can fail over in case one of them fails to operate.

I understand the host on the left (ldap1) is always a primary server OBIEE will authenticate. If the primary server is down, OBIEE will authenticate the secondary server on the right (ldap2) instead. Unfortunately, when ldap1 is down and I log in OBIEE page with my AD user, it will keep forever loading with a white page. Interestingly, when ldap1 is still up and ldap2 is down, it also keeps loading with a white page. This is a weird situation how the secondary server being down while the primary server being up affects the authentication.

I would like to seek suggestions how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Both - or "all" if you have more than 2 - providers must be set as SUFFICIENT since WLS parses them in the sequence you configured.

So for example 1 = LDAP1, 2 = LDAP2, 3 = DefaultAuthenticator.

Also, you must have the virtualize = true parameter configured for WLS to actually cycle through all provisers and not just stop after the first one.

Comment: We set virtualize = true. Did you mean I should create another MSAD_Provider for ldap2 instead of filling in multiple hosts in one MSAD_Provider?

Comment: Yes. You need one provider per source in your realm.

Comment: I split into MSAD_Provider and MSAD_Provider2, to no avail. Do I have to look into any logs to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes you can pump up the logging to 32 - process is explained here: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-994048

It's for 11g but the log level config is the same